# Convolutional Neural Network starts training with a very high accuracy, and decreases with each epoch

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

My code:

```
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(64, 64, 1)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(24, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(16, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(144, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(3, activation='sigmoid'))
```

```
model.compile(optimizer='sgd',
              loss = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=50, 
                    validation_data=(val_images, val_labels))
```

The library I used is Tensorflow/Keras.

The training process is acting very weird. The first epoch starts with an accuracy of over 90%, and with each epoch, it decreases up to 50% by the end of 50 epochs. Sometimes it goes back up to 70% at random times. Those are the accuracies on validation and train data. However on test data, the result is 0%.

The problem is a multi-label classification one. There are 3 labels, 2 classes each (0 and 1).

In case you want to test the code and reproduce the problem, here is the link to the dataset:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1jC7aYmMJdM55-DMwZkNEwhr-_A3uxO9-?usp=sharing

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Configuration seems correct because OP says that's multi-label classification.

Comment: @Frightera Oh yes, I misread, then the problem is inappropriate accuracy metric, I don't think the standard keras accuracy supports multi-label, the OP would need to have a per-class accuracy.

Comment: I think it might be attributed to your imbalanced dataset. If that is really the case, you may want to try a more insightful metric like AUC (more likely with the PR  curve), for which you can find more information on https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/AUC (note the `multi_label` and `label_weights` arguments).

Comment: Hi @Ann, The link is not accessible. Please provide access to the reproducible code link.

Comment: @TFer2, the link should be fixed.